# Is there any way to create filterable HTML tables in SAS?

Tags: sas

I create an html output in SAS

```
ods html style=analysis body="...html" ; 
proc print data=test;
title= 'test ' ;
run;
ods html close;
```

The table is okay, however I would like this table to be more interactive . . . **Is there any way this table could have filters for the columns**, like an excel spreadsheet does , so that the user could filter out by name or by other characteristics ? My table is too big, and not very convenient  . . . Does SAS has any such option ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the [Tableeditor tagset](https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsmarkup/tableeditor/index.html).  That is a SAS provided tagset that can be used to make tables, including filterable/sortable tables.

The specific code from that article that you'd use something like:

```
ods tagsets.tableeditor file="c:\temp.html"
    options(autofilter="yes"
            autofilter_width="7em"
            autofilter_table="1"

            ) style=styles.mystyle ;

proc print data=sashelp.orsales(obs=100);
run;

ods tagsets.tableeditor close;
```

This assumes you are trying to make a local HTML file.  If you want to put this on the web for someone, you should be using SAS/Intrnet and/or various BI packages.

You also could produce an excel file using `ods excel` (in 9.4 TS1M0) or `ods tagsets.excelxp` (in 9.1.3-9.4), which both have an autofilter option directly.

Answer (score 2):

For the best results I'd use something like jQuery datatables:

https://datatables.net/

An example of a table with multi-column filtering is shown here:

https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

First I'd take the existing HTML output that SAS produces and modify it by hand until you get the jQuery datatable working.  I'd start with a simple filter first, and then attempt a multi-column filter. Once you have this working you will know what the final file to be produced by SAS must look like.

To implement this in SAS, I'd create 2 template files that will effectively be the top of the HTML file (header), and the bottom of the HTML file (footer).  You will build these yourself in your HTML-editor/text-editor of choice.

SAS will create everything inbetween which will pretty much just be the  `<TABLE> ... </TABLE>`.  You can do this using the `BODY` option on the ODS statement I believe.

In SAS you will read in the header file and output it to a destination filename.  You will then use ODS to append the table to the same destination file.  Finally you will read in the footer file and append it to the same destination.

If you didn't want to use 'template' files, you could even just have SAS use `put` statements to write the necessary HTML to the file before and after ODS does it's thing.

Comment: I've done exactly this, writing a custom tagset which integrates datatables into ODS, accepting options on the ODS statement, plus it works with spanned headers.

Comment: @Chris J - That's a great idea. I might look into doing something similar for myself.  If there were any invaluable resources you used would you mind linking them?

Answer (score 1):

To fully expand on the solution myself and Rob outlined, here's the basic code to build a new tagset incorporating the jQuery datatables plugin.

(Apologies for the formatting - had to wrap it all in a `<code><pre>` block so the script tags were retained)

First create the tagset, amending the paths (either absolute, or relative to the html location) to jQuery, Datatables and the Datatable CSS accordingly. The tagset can be written to a permanent library if you choose, or work.

Tested with jQuery 1.4.2 and Datatables 1.7.0 beta 2 (wrote it a while ago!)

I also modified the Datatables plugin so that it sorts SAS date9 values correctly, but that's outside the scope of this post.

`%LET LIB= work ;`

%MACRO BUILD_TAGSET(TAGSET=,COLS=) ;
  ods path &LIB..TEMPLAT(UPDATE) SASSTORE.TEMPLAT(READ) SASUSER.TEMPLAT(READ) SASHELP.TMPLMST(READ) ;
  /* EVENTROW is the number of rows generated within the THEAD element of the report, i.e. the 
     last row is the row to which the TH elements have the event listeners added by jQuery.
     COLS is the number of columns on the report. Not usually required.
     By default all columns are searchable and sortable */

proc template ;
    define tagset &TAGSET ;
      parent=tagsets.htmlcss ;

```
 define event initialize ;
   do / if $options["EVENT_ROW"] ;
     set $event_row $options["EVENT_ROW"] ;
   else ;
     set $event_row '1' ;
   done ;

   do / if $options["TABLEID"] ;
     set $tableid $options["TABLEID"] ;
   else ;
     set $tableid 'default_table' ;
   done ;
 end ;

 define event doc_head ;
    start:
      put "<head>" NL ;
      put "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' src='/media/js/jquery.js'></script>" NL
          "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js'></script>" NL
          "<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>" NL
          "  $(document).ready(function() {" NL
          "    oTable = $('#" $tableid "').dataTable({" NL
          "                             'bJQueryUI': false," NL
          "                             'iDisplayLength': 50," NL
          "                             'sPaginationType': 'two_button'," NL
%IF &COLS ne %THEN %DO ;
          "                             'aoColumns': [" NL
  %DO _I = 1 %TO &N ;
          "                              {'bSortable':true} " %IF &_I < &N %THEN %DO ; "," %END ; NL
  %END ;
          "                             ]," NL
%END ;
          "                             'bStateSave': false," NL
          "                             'iCookieDuration': 21600" NL /* SaveState cookie duration = 12 hours */
          "    });" NL
          "  } );" NL
          "</script>" NL
          "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/demo_table_jui.css'>" NL /* Change path to stylesheet here */
          "<style type='text/css'>" NL
          "  #" $tableid " { margin-top: 12px }" NL
          "</style>" NL
          ;
      put VALUE NL ;

   finish:
      put "</head>" NL ;
 end ;

 define event header ;
    start:
       do /if cmp( htmlclass, "DataEmphasis") and cmp ( colstart, "1");
          set $filter_row data_row;
          put "</tbody>" NL;
          put "<tfoot>" NL;
          put "<tr class=""noFilter"">" NL;
       done;

       do /if cmp( row, $event_row) ;
          put "<th" ; /* TH for last row in header      */
       else ;
          put "<td" ; /* TD for non-last rows in header */
       done ;

       putq " id=" HTMLID ;
       putq " headers=" headers /if $header_data_associations ;
       putq " title=" flyover ;

       trigger classalign ;
       trigger style_inline ;
       trigger rowcol ;
       put ">" ;

       trigger cell_value ;

    finish:
       trigger cell_value ;

       do /if cmp( row, $event_row) ;
          put "</th>" NL ;
       else ;
          put "</td>" NL ;
       done ;
  end ;

define event table_body;
  put "<tbody";
  put ">" NL;

  finish:
    do /if ^exist( $filter_row);
      put "</tbody>" NL;
    else;
      put "</tfoot>" NL;
    done;
end;

define event row;
  do /if cmp(section, 'head') ;
    put "<tr>" NL ;
  done ;

  finish:
    put "</tr>" NL;
end;

define event data;
  start:
     do /if ^cmp( htmlclass, "DataEmphasis") and cmp ( colstart, "1");
        put "<tr>" NL;
     done;

     do /if cmp( htmlclass, "DataEmphasis") and cmp ( colstart, "1");
        set $filter_row data_row;
        put "</tbody>" NL;
        put "<tfoot>" NL;
        put "<tr class=""noFilter"">" NL;
     done;

     trigger header /breakif cmp( htmlclass, "RowHeader");

     trigger header /breakif cmp( htmlclass, "Header");

     put "<td";
     putq " id=" HTMLID;
     putq " headers=" headers /if $header_data_associations;
     putq " title=" flyover;

     trigger classalign;

     trigger style_inline;

     trigger rowcol;
     put " nowrap" /if no_wrap;
     put ">";

     trigger cell_value;

  finish:
     trigger header /breakif cmp( htmlclass, "RowHeader");

     trigger header /breakif cmp( htmlclass, "Header");

     trigger cell_value;

     put "</td>" NL;
  end;

end ;
```

run ;
  ods path &LIB..TEMPLAT(READ) SASSTORE.TEMPLAT(READ) SASUSER.TEMPLAT(READ) SASHELP.TMPLMST(READ) ;
%MEND BUILD_TAGSET ;

%BUILD_TAGSET(TAGSET=&LIB..datatables) ;

Then whenever you wish to use the tagset, assign the ODS PATH :

```
  ods path &LIB..TEMPLAT(READ) SASSTORE.TEMPLAT(READ) SASUSER.TEMPLAT(READ) SASHELP.TMPLMST(READ) ;
```

Then use ODS TAGSETs to create your output, e.g.

```
ods &LIB..datatables body="c:\Datatable.htm" style=styles.sasweb 
  options (event_row='1' tableid='table1')  ;

proc report data=sashelp.class 
  style(REPORT)={htmlid='table1'} ;
run ;
title;
ods &LIB..datatables close ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Here is the link to a very good article . http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/266-2008.pdf

On page 10 it explains everything.

If you are familiar with javascript this should not be a problem for you . just include

`headtext='<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JAVASCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT" 
 SRC="c:\temp\sorttable.js"></script>'`

Comment: Thnak you +1 but i did not find any filter information